# Scrapy pipeline errors - list item usage

Tags: python, csv, attributes, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to crawl a site and create a CSV out of three elements, we'll say 'id,' 'name,' and 'desc,' to keep with the Scrapy site pipeline example.  I'm scraping these items and outputting them to a csv.  I don't want any ROWS with the same 'id' string.

This is the example pipeline for Scrapy:

```
class DuplicatesPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['id'] in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(item['id'])
            return item
```

But when I use that code, I get `exceptions.TypeError: unhashable type:'list'`

However, if I try to convert to a tuple, a la:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if tuple(item.get('id', '')) in self.ids_seen:
        raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
    else:
        self.ids_seen.add(item.get['id'])
        return item
```

I get `exceptions.TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Can someone please let me know how to use the item pipelines to simply not allow multiple rows with the same 'id' strings in the 'id' column?  I may be way off in denying a single element when I don't want blank spots in the cells, either - I want the whole row to get skipped if they share an 'id' item.  I may also be way off in using the pipeline for this, when I may need something in the csvexporter or a csv spider or something.  Seems like this would be an easy job with Scrapy.

---

SOLUTION?

I think I solved it by changing the initial code to this to make a string:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
        idstring = str(item['id'])
        if idstring in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(idstring)
            return item
```

Please let me know if this is a problematic solution, as I'm a total Python newb :)

Comment: `exceptions.TypeError: unhashable type:'list'` probably comes from `self.ids_seen.add(item['id'])` where `item['id']` must be a list and not a string or integer, or a hashable type basically. You should look at how you set the `"id"` field for your items. Are you using a selector with `.select(...).extract()`, which returns a list, without selecting the first element? Please share your spider code, or snippet of it, for us to help you with it.

Comment: I am using `hxs.select(...).extract()` in the spider.  However, the new code converting the item to a string really seems to be working. Since I have no idea what I'm doing, and that seems too easy of a solution, I'm wondering what problems I should anticipate with this shortcut.  I don't even know why converting a list to a string *would* work, but I'm getting no duplicates and a similar ratio of reported duplicates to what I was getting before by filtering them out of the resulting CSV...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mh, I guess you could change your Pipeline to use a list instead of a set.

Try change:

```
class DuplicatesPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['id'] in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(item['id'])
            return item
```

into:

```
class DuplicatesPipeline(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.ids_seen = []

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if item['id'] in self.ids_seen:
        raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
    else:
        self.ids_seen.append(item['id'])
        return item
```

Cheers